# WPF Binding to a property obtained from a DataTemplate

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, data-binding, datatemplate

I want to bind a property of one object to a similar property of one of its child objects, while this child content (including the value of the property in question) is obtained from a `DataTemplate`. This is all happening in a `UserControl`, if it matters.

```
<UserControl.Resources>
  <DataTemplate x:Key="RText">
    <TextBlock Text="TextR" ToolTip="TextR"/>
  </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>

<StackPanel x:Name="LayoutRoot" ToolTip="{Binding Path=ToolTip, ElementName=TemplText, FallbackValue='error'}">
  <TextBlock Text="Some common static text " />
  <ContentControl x:Name="TemplText" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource RText}" />
</StackPanel>
```

Also, in code-behind, in the constructor of this control, there is an assignment

`LayoutRoot.DataContext = this`

which is apparently required in order to bind to `UserControl`'s own properties (this is not shown in the snippet). I guess it doesn't matter for this problem anyway, but I do need this line.

The idea is this: the whole `StackPanel` (`LayoutRoot`) should have the same `ToolTip` as the `ContentControl` (`TemplText`). However, this tooltip should be taken from the specified template, i.e. be "TextR" in this case.

The underlying reason for this approach is that the `ContentControl` will eventually be selected via a rather complicated `DataTemplateSelector` (assigned to `ContentTemplateSelector` rather than `ContentTemplate`), and I want to avoid creating a similar selector for the general tooltip. I'd rather include the tooltip in the template selected and then propagate it up to cover the whole control. All the elements, including the ToolTip, will also be much more elaborated rather than just `TextBlock`, and it's not practical to make the whole thing (`StackPanel`) a selectable template.

The code above doesn't work in the sense that the tooltip is not shown for the whole control; it shows up for the `TemplText` only. However, the `FallbackValue` is also not shown, which indicates that there is no problem with the path: it finds the element but presumably takes the `ToolTip` directly from it (which is `null`) rather than from the template.

Is there a work-around to this problem? or maybe just a better WPF approach to achieving the same result? I'm new to WPF.

I understand that the `DataTemplate` itself doesn't have a ToolTip; it's one of its elements that does. But how can I refer to it? Or should I use a Style that belongs to the template somehow?

Answer (score 0):

1.Set your `Binding` in code in `Window.Activated` event.

```
private void Window_Activated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Binding b = new Binding("ToolTip");
    b.Source = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(TemplText, 0), 0);
    LayoutRoot.SetBinding(StackPanel.ToolTipProperty, b);
}
```

2.Set `ToolTip` from a property in `ViewModel`.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="RText">
    <TextBlock x:Name="Tb" Text="TextR" ToolTip="{Binding ToolTipProp}"/>
</DataTemplate>

<StackPanel x:Name="LayoutRoot" ToolTip="{Binding DataContext.ToolTipProp, ElementName=TemplText}">
```

Comment: What is `ToolTipProp` here?

Comment: It would be a property in your viewmodel. you will define this property. it would be a normal CLR property, as 2 way binding is not needed.

Comment: But this assumes that I assign the tooltip programmatically?.. Yet I don't want to do it. The whole idea is that the code should only select a `DataTemplate`, and the template would statically define the appropriate tooltip. There is just one suitable tooltip for a given template.